# Observable Array *ngFor directive Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I'm stuck with "ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

I'm trying to set up a Basket store to provide data to my BasketPage.

In my service i got :

```
nourritureArrayTest: Nourriture[] = [];
getNourriturePanier(): Observable<Nourriture[]> {
  return of(this.nourritureArrayTest)
}
```

in my Basket Page ts :

```
nourriturePanierTest: Observable<Nourriture[]>
ngOnInit() {
  this.nourriturePanierTest= this.panierService.getNourriturePanier()
}
```

nourritureArrayTest is an array of object of type

in my Basket.html

```
<div *ngFor="let extra of nourriturePanierTest | async">
<p>{{extra.name}}</p></div>
```

Comment: `nourriturePanierTest ` must be Array type.  check  `nourriturePanierTest` in console

Comment: In your Basket Page you should be subscribing to the observable and storing the value the subscription delivers to you.

Comment: everything working fine check  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mq5yitasonWhite

Comment: its working fine

Comment: Yeah that error you're getting must come from another part of your code you're not sharing. What you posted should work fine. See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-onxjsp) for a dummy sample (above one gives a 404).

Comment: this the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mq5yit

Comment: well yeah it's working now...i have NO CLUE why it wasn't...i just replaced my code with the working exemple of blitzstack then replaced each block with what i had previously and this time it worked...some kind of magic...

Answer (score 0):

nourriturePanierTest is an observable. You need to store this observable in some array and then use that array inside an ngFor.

ngFor only works on Array.

I've added some code for your help.

```
nourriturePanierTest: Nourriture[];
ngOnInit() {
this.nourriturePanierTest= this.panierService.getNourriturePanier().subscribe(res=>{
this.nourriturePanierTest= res })
}
```

Comment: Well this goes against my ¦ async pipe doesn't it?

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mq5yitasonWhite  async pipe will do this magic for you 

Comment: Page requested couldn't be found :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the observable instead of assigning it to a variable:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.panierService.getNourriturePanier().subscribe(res=>{
    this.nourriturePanierTest= res
  })
}
```

and it will work if this.nourritureArrayTest is an array

Comment: You don't need to subscribe from the component's script if you're using the `async` pipe.